# Remote jupyter notebook vagrant and pycharm

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a local development environtment using `Pycharm Professional Edition`, `Vagrant` and `Jupyter notebook`.

I am able to connect to `Jupyter notebook` with the browser from the `host` to the `vagrant` machine using `http://localhost:8888`.

I tried to connect to the `Jupyter notebook` from `PyCharm` with token but it did not work, so I changed the login option to password, setting it as `vagrant`.

Also I have change a remote interpreter, which is `python3` on the vagrant machine

Despite I have already changed the `Jupyter Notebook` settings on `Pycharm` to password login, I receive on the vagrant the following response:

```
[W 16:47:03.263 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 16:47:03.264 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/kernels (10.0.2.2) 1.35ms referer=None
```

Is it possible to run remote Notebook with Pycharm and Vagrant?